# ClassNotFoundException in Tomcat 6 when a JAR is deleted

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, classloader

There are two JARs in WEB-INF/lib:

- package1.jar (contains org.example.package1)
- package2.jar (contains org.example.package2)

There are no dependencies between the two.

Now I delete package1.jar without reloading the context.

If I load a JSP page that uses package2.jar, I get the following error:

```
04.04.2014 09:18:56 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SCHWERWIEGEND: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.example.package2.ClassName
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:128)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:66)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2699)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:326)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:150)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:340)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:270)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:268)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:517)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:302)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:163)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.access$000(ApplicationFilterChain.java:56)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
    at com.relounge.badenova.filter.HttpHeaderFilter.doFilter(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:270)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:268)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:517)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:302)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.access$000(ApplicationFilterChain.java:56)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:190)
    at org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:291)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:776)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:705)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:898)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:690)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Why can´t Tomcat find the classes from package2.jar, although they are present in the file system?

Comment: Can you post the complete log of the exception

Comment: May be the jar is not in the class path or the class you think present in the jar is not actually present.

Comment: I forgot to mention: After reloading the context, the error disappears. package2.jar is not used anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can clean your project and then you have to build it manually. Then the all classes will be build again and then this error should be fix